# How to append to Azure Storage Account (Gen2) AppendBlob without (409) Conflict

Tags: c#, .net, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a method that accepts a blob directory and a memory stream of text that needs to be read line by line and appended to an Azure AppendBlob. My storage account is a general purpose v2 (Standard/Hot tier) with Data Lake Gen 2 enabled.
At present I am not able to append to blobs due to getting a 409 Conflict error even though no other users are writing to this container.

Given below is a cut down (for simplicity) version of my code with the same issue:
Note the code is written for .net 4.6:

```
/* the following libraries are in use
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
*/

static void WriteCSV(
    Stream csvStream, 
    CloudBlobContainer tgtContaine // this is a Gen 2 container
    )
{
    csvStream.Position = 0;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(csvStream))
    {
        string csvFileName = "test-append-blob" + $@"_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHHmmss")}.csv";
        
        CloudAppendBlob blobCSVFile = tgtContaine.GetAppendBlobReference("iso/dwh/" + csvFileName); // need to create this in this directory
        
        if (!blobCSVFile.Exists()) blobCSVFile.CreateOrReplace(); // at this point I can see the empty file being created

        while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
        {
            string csvLine = sr.ReadLine();
            
            // some additional logic ommited for brevity

            blobCSVFile.AppendText(csvLine); // 409 conflict occures here !!!
        }
    }
}
```

There are some reasons I am using append blob and writing line by line, one of which is the potential chance for large stream content and related memory concerns.

Could you please guide me in the correct approach to achieve this ? and why would there be 409 conflict here when no other processors or sessions are using this container/directory ?

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the message you are getting along with 409 code? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-service-error-codes

Comment: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException : The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. ---> System.Net.WebException : The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode,HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode,T retVal,StorageCommandBase`1 cmd,Exception ex)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudAppendBlob.<AppendBlockImpl>b__76(RESTCommand`1 cmd,HttpWebResponse resp,Exception ex,OperationContext ctx)\r\n

Comment: What is your blob SDK nuget version?

Comment: Azure.Storage.Blobs (12.2.0)

Comment: Your code does not seem to be using Azure.Storage.Blobs aka [V12 sdk](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet). I think you are using [V11 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet#version-11x)

Comment: krishg I think you are right even though I have that nuget package I am using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob. This is due to an dependency I have for .net 4.6. So is it the case that AppendBlobs will not work with the legacy SDK ?

Comment: what is the version of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob you are using?

Comment: This is the assembly reference Assembly Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=7.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Comment: Oops that's ancient! I suspect it's using a lot older version of API. 409 can occur also because "The operation for AppendBlob requires at least version 2015-02-21 (API version)"...try updating your `WindowsAzure.Storage` nuget to latest version.

Comment: Any luck after updating?

Comment: As per nuget page Version 7.2.1 was last updated on 2016-09-19. The latest version is 9.3.3 (2018-11-17). Apparently looks like even the latest version is deprecated as is recommended to move to Azure.Storage.Blobs. Unfortunately it seems like Azure.Storage.Blobs as a dependency on .Net Core or Standard which at present I am unable to move to due to some .Net Fx dependant 3rd party libraries which I need to use or the business requirement. For the moment I am using  UploadFromStream which is not ideal.

Comment: Azure.Storage.Blobs is compatible with .net framework 4.6.1+ since it is .net standard 2.0 compliant.

Comment: I have installed the Azure.Storage.Blobs nuget, but when I specify using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blobs it says "type or namespace 'Storage' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure'

Comment: Yes because namespace has changed. Refer my other answer related to Blob nuget [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64185751/how-to-replace-microsoft-windowsazure-storage-with-microsoft-azure-storage-blob/64203656#64203656)