# Azure function, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage missing

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I had a working http triggered Azure function a year ago. Not anymore. I created new azure function (runtime ~4) and now I can not compile it in Azure editor. It says "[Error] run.csx(2,1): error CS0006: Metadata file 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage' could not be found".
It is simply geting list of files from my Azure BLOB storage. I am loosing my mind, I don't know what to cofigure, or how to change my code. Is Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage no loner supported?
I was wondering about lowering my runtime version, but it is grey-out (I can not change it).
I read this [How to replace Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage with Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64185751/how-to-replace-microsoft-windowsazure-storage-with-microsoft-azure-storage-blob) But I trying #r "Azure.Storage.Blobs" have the same result

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];
    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

string connectionString = "MY_CONNECTION_STRING";
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

CloudBlobClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
string rootDirectoryName = name.Replace(" ", "");
CloudBlobContainer container = client.GetContainerReference("storage");
CloudBlobDirectory folder = container.GetDirectoryReference(rootDirectoryName);
CloudBlobDirectory modelFolder = folder.GetDirectoryReference("giftpics");

BlobResultSegment segment = await modelFolder.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null);
                    List<IListBlobItem> list = new List<IListBlobItem>();
                    list.AddRange(segment.Results);
                    while (segment.ContinuationToken != null)
                    {
                        segment = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(segment.ContinuationToken);
                        list.AddRange(segment.Results);
                    }
List<string> blobNames = list.OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().Select(b => b.Name.Replace(rootDirectoryName, "").Replace("giftpics", "").Replace("/", "")).ToList();

  string contents = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(blobNames);
     return new OkObjectResult(contents);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled on this too.....I think I might have found a solution for it, not sure.  But try this, it might work:

1. Upload an empty function.proj in the Azure Portal (ie while in the 'Code + Test' view while editing your Azure Function)
2. Select the function.proj file (using the dropdown)
3. Manually enter (or copy/paste) your code into the function.proj.  You should have a screen that looks something like below at this point:

[image]

4. Save.  It should now be restoring packages and hopefully compile your code successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your runtime to ~3.  This worked for me, but I am not a developer so I have no idea what any ramifications this might have.