# Metadata file could not be found - azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to run an azure function app function that has a cosmos trigger and makes a request to an API but I keep getting compilation errors.

[image]

[image]

I've tried adding **`Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core`** to a project.json file and to a function.proj file as a dependency and its still throwing the same errors. The **`fuction app runtime is ~4`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add the **`Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core`** dependency locally and then publish your Local cosmos DB Function to Function app like below:-

**Add the nuget package in your function code like below:-**

[image]

Now Publish this Function in your Function app this will deploy all the required dependency in your Function app too like below:-

[image]

[image]

The package will be part of Function app's bin as a dll like below:-

[image]

***If you have created the cosmosDB Trigger in the Portal make sure You can add the csproj file below in Azure Functions App by referring my [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76378498/unable-to-connect-to-azure-storage-table-using-azure-portal-function-net/76404187#76404187). This will install all the required dependency in your function app successfully.***

[image]

**My Csproj file:-**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <UserSecretsId>47b55f40-2914-480e-874c-c01dc0f29915</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core" Version="2.20.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB" Version="3.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Refer this [SO thread answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70415907/azure-function-microsoft-windowsazure-storage-missing) by Graham Watkins ***Downgrading Function runtime to 3*** has helped.