# BlobTrigger Func VSCode. Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ParameterBindingData' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=3.0.34.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools, azure-blob-trigger

I'm trying to make an example of BlobTrigger Azure Function using Visual Studio Code.
For that I was following along the Book "Beginning Azure Functions" of Rahul Sawhney.

My csproj file is:

```
  <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <RootNamespace>blob_trigger</RootNamespace>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.2.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="3.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

My Function class is:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Png;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;

namespace AzureFunctionV2Book.Function
{
    public static class BlobTriggerCSharp
    {
        [FunctionName("BlobTriggerCSharp")]
        public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("image-blob/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, [Blob("output-blob/{name}", FileAccess.ReadWrite, Connection ="AzureWebJobsStorage")] CloudBlockBlob outputBlob, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");

            var width = 100;
            var height = 200;
            var encoder = new PngEncoder();
            using (var output = new MemoryStream())
            using (Image<Rgba32> image = (Image<Rgba32>)Image.Load(myBlob)) {
                image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(width, height));
                image.Save(output, encoder);
                output.Position = 0;
                await outputBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My local.settings.json file is:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=buildingazurefunctionsfr;AccountKey=somekey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=buildingazurefunctionsfr;AccountKey=somekey;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE": "building-azure-functions-fromvscodebed7b8",
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE": "1",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "app-key"
  }
}
```

When I try to run the code, I get the following error:

[2023-10-20T15:17:59.993Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation 'f67d9178-3d34-43ab-8715-a2a55f227595'.
[2023-10-20T15:17:59.998Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ParameterBindingData' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve "Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ParameterBindingData'" in Python Azure Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76202060/how-to-resolve-could-not-load-type-microsoft-azure-webjobs-parameterbindingdat)

Comment: @Code4Fun, check the version in host.json if version is `[3.*, 4.0.0)` change it to `[4.0.0, 5.0.0)`.

Comment: @Code4Fun -  Are you getting the error locally or in Azure ?

Comment: I'm working locally. I'm getting this error if I try to use extensionBundel: Extension bundle configuration should not be present for the function app with pre-compiled functions. Please remove extension bundle configuration from host.json: C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\VisualStudioCode\blob-trigger\bin\Debug\net6.0\host.json

Comment: Can you please share how you are using `extensionBundle`.

Comment: `{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "concurrency": {
    "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
    "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 5.0.0)"
  }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I was getting the same error when I tried with the configuration with versions `[3.0.0, 4.0.0)` and `[4.*, 5.0.0)`:**

[image]

- So, I had to use the below configuration in `host.json` to fix the above issue:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    },
    "extensionBundle": {
      "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
      "version": "[3.*, 3.9.0)"
    }
  }
}
```

---

- I have followed [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=python-v2,in-process,nodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example) to implement Blob Trigger Output binding with below code:

**Code Snippet:**

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
[StorageAccount("con")]
public static void Run([BlobTrigger("sample-images/{name}")] Stream image,
    [Blob("sample-images-sm/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream imageSmall,
    [Blob("sample-images-md/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream imageMedium)
{
        IImageFormat format;

    using (Image<Rgba32> input = Image.Load<Rgba32>(image, out format))
    {
        ResizeImage(input, imageSmall, ImageSize.Small, format);
    }

    image.Position = 0;
    using (Image<Rgba32> input = Image.Load<Rgba32>(image, out format))
    {
        ResizeImage(input, imageMedium, ImageSize.Medium, format);
    }
}

public static void ResizeImage(Image<Rgba32> input, Stream output, ImageSize size, IImageFormat format)
{
    var dimensions = imageDimensionsTable[size];

    input.Mutate(x => x.Resize(dimensions.Item1, dimensions.Item2));
    input.Save(output, format);
}

public enum ImageSize { ExtraSmall, Small, Medium }

private static Dictionary<ImageSize, (int, int)> imageDimensionsTable = new Dictionary<ImageSize, (int, int)>() {
    { ImageSize.ExtraSmall, (320, 200) },
    { ImageSize.Small,      (640, 400) },
    { ImageSize.Medium,     (800, 600) }
};
```

**Uploading Image to Container:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

- ***Resized, created a blob automatically and uploaded the Resized Images(as per code):***

[image]

**Updating answer as per the comments:**

> [2023-10-30T13:42:50.935Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'BlobTriggerCSharp'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind Blob to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob'.
> [2023-10-30T13:42:50.938Z] Possible causes:

I was also getting the same error:

[image]

- As per my [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64203656), got to know that **CloudBlockBlob** class is only supported with `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob(deprecated package)`.
- Instead, we need to use **BlobClient** or **BlobCloudClient** class to achieve the same which is part of **Azure.Storage.Blobs** package(latest).

[image]

---

I have reproduced the same using your code with few modifications as shown below:

**Code Snippet:**

```cs
[FunctionName("BlobTrigger")]
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "conn")] Stream myBlob, string name, [Blob("output-blob/{name}", FileAccess.ReadWrite, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] BlockBlobClient outputBlob, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");
    var width = 100;
    var height = 200;
    var encoder = new PngEncoder();
    using (var output = new MemoryStream())
    using (Image<Rgba32> image = (Image<Rgba32>)Image.Load(myBlob))
    {
        image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(width, height));
        image.Save(output, encoder);
        output.Position = 0;
        await outputBlob.UploadAsync(output);

    }   
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Pravallika, I keep getting the error if I try to use extensionBundle. Moreover, in VS Code the code above does not compile. The out shows up squiggly!                       You are posting me another example, but I want to get my code running

Comment: [2023-10-25T14:51:51.738Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '371c1529-73f2-4a40-b504-ae8e5bc53d7c'.
[2023-10-25T14:51:51.744Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.Queues: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ParameterBindingData' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs, Version=3.0.34.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Comment: Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.4895 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.13.0.19486

Comment: Install the package  `Azure.Storage.Queues` version `12.11.1`.

Comment: I tried with your code as well initially and got the same error as yours. To resolve that I added extension bundle version `[3.*, 3.9.0)` and installed the packages `Azure.Storage.Blobs` and `Azure.Storage.Queues`.

Comment: If I try to install version 12.11.1 I get an error. I've installed the 2 packages `<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.16.0" />` but I'm still getting the same error. If I add the ext. bundle I get an error too: `Extension bundle configuration should not be present for the function app with pre-compiled functions. Please remove extension bundle configuration from host.json: C:\Users\MARCO\Documents\VisualStudioCode\blob-trigger\bin\Debug\net6.0\host.json`

Comment: Downgrade the version of  `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage` package to **5.0.1**.

Comment: `<PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Queues" Version="12.11.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="3.0.2" />`

Comment: With extension bundle it does not work. Without extension bundle I get now this error: `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'BlobTriggerCSharp'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind Blob to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob'.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255740/discussion-between-pravallika-kv-and-code4fun).

Comment: Hi Pravallika, many thanks for your help. It solved my issue. I have used `BlockBlobClient` and in the `host.json` file `extensionBundle`, `"version": "[3.*, 3.9.0)"`

Answer (score 0):

**WORKING CODE**

```
    namespace AzureFunctionV2Book.Function
{
    public class BlobTriggerCSharp
    {
        [FunctionName("BlobTriggerCSharp")]
        public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("image-blob/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, [Blob("output-blob/{name}", FileAccess.ReadWrite, Connection ="AzureWebJobsStorage")] BlockBlobClient outputBlob, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");

            var width = 100;
            var height = 200;
            var encoder = new PngEncoder();
            using (var output = new MemoryStream())
            using (Image<Rgb24> image = (SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image<SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats.Rgb24>)Image.Load(myBlob)) {
                image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(width, height));
                image.Save(output, encoder);
                output.Position = 0;
                await outputBlob.UploadAsync(output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the host.json is

```
{
"version": "2.0",
"logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
        "samplingSettings": {
            "isEnabled": true,
            "excludedTypes": "Request"
        },
        "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    },
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[3.*, 3.9.0)"
    }
}
```

}